# You cannot commit during a managed transaction in Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, database, hibernate, transactions, criteria

Good day,

Below is my original code:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession( ).createCriteria(
                JSNumber.class );
criteria.add( Restrictions.eq( "paymentDate", mnight ) );
JSNumber result = (JSNumber) criteria
                .uniqueResult( );

int newNo = result.getRunningNo( ) + 1;
result.setRunningNo( newNo );
getSession( ).merge( result );
getSession( ).flush( );
```

This is to get a running number from JSNumber table. Let say the number is 12, then + 1 to become 13, and then udpate the running number to 13 in database.

There is a bug which is when the time is almost the same, just within millisecond , two request to get result/update from/to this table, it may return same result for both's user request.

For example, First request at 14:47:36.735 and Second request at 14:47:36.737 First request get value = 110, and it will update it to 111. But before first request update the value, second request already get the value, which is 110 also.

I am trying to use `beginTransaction()` to handle this case. The following is my new code :

```
Transaction tx = null;
tx = getSession().beginTransaction( );

Criteria criteria = getSession( ).createCriteria(
                JSNumber.class );
criteria.add( Restrictions.eq( "paymentDate", mnight ) );
JSNumber result = (JSNumber) criteria
                .uniqueResult( );

int newNo = result.getRunningNo( ) + 1;
result.setRunningNo( newNo );
getSession( ).merge( result );
getSession( ).flush( );

tx.commit( );
```

This will hit `java.sql.SQLException: You cannot commit during a managed transaction!`

I am new to Hibernate. Kindly advise what is the mistake I make. I try to google long time but look like cant find a way that I understand.

Comment: can you share your configuration (xml) for hibernate.?

Comment: Wrapping this code in a transaction is not going to help, because that in itself does not prevent another transaction from reading the old value. This is not a trivial problem to solve; google "lost update problem".

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that your transaction 
 is being managed by other that hibernate (most probably the Container) .
That's the Exception is about .
In case of these managed environment Hibernate cannot handle Transaction by it self.
Transaction handling (begin, commit, or rollback database transactions) done by that managed environment.

Please Read [transactions-demarcation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-demarcation) for understanding the reason clearly

Comment: Is there any way to solve my problem ? I means `There is a bug which is when the time is almost the same, just within millisecond , two request to get result/update from/to this table, it may return same result for both's user request.` as I mention in question.

Comment: definitely there is a way. Can you update your question with your hibernate configuration xml.?